# How to prove that a diffrensiation of a formula equals to another formula.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

QUESTION 1) if $y =\dfrac{ \sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x+\cos x}$  show that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{x^2}{(x\sin x+\cos x)^2}$

QUESTION 2) if $y = \dfrac{\tan x+1}{\tan x-1}$ show that $\dfrac{dy}{dx}= \dfrac{-2}{1-\sin 2x}$

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange. Here's a formatting guide http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . I'd help edit your question but I don't know what is included in your fractions. If you show what you've attempted so far, we can help you.

Comment: Do you mean to have parentheses around $\sin{x}-x\cos{x}$ as well as elsewhere?

Comment: no - means mines while / devide

Comment: y = sinx-xcosx\xsinx+cosx show that dy\dx= x^2\(xsinx+cosx)^2

Comment: So what part of this confuses you? Where are you stuck? (Do you know the quotient rule for derivatives, and the derivatives of the various trigonometric functions?)

Comment: @AhmdinhoMufasa That's exactly what you'd written before. Copy-pasting it doesn't help anyone. If you add brackets to your fractions, we can know what is included. For example "sinx/(cosx+1)" instead of "sinx/cosx +1".

Comment: @EulCan i was trying to edit it but thanx to the admin he did that for me

Comment: @rogerl for the first question i can diffrensiate the first ster but what confuses me is how to prove sinx-xcosx = x^2

Comment: @rogerl yeah i know the quotient rule but am still stuck to prove that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, we get
\begin{align}
    \frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{ \sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x+\cos x}\right)
    &= \frac{(x\sin x + \cos x)(\cos x + x\sin x-\cos x)-(\sin x - x\cos x)(\sin x + x\cos x - \sin x)}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2} \\
    &= \frac{x^2\sin^2 x + x\sin x\cos x - (x\sin x\cos x - x^2\cos^2 x)}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2} \\
    &= \frac{x^2(\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x)}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2} \\
    &= \frac{x^2}{(x\sin x + \cos x)^2} .
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

for the second, we get

$$\begin{align}
y&=\frac{\tan x+1}{\tan x-1}\\
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\tan x+1}{\tan x-1}\right)\\&
=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(\tan x+1)(\tan x-1)-(\tan x+1)\frac{d}{dx}(\tan x-1)}{(\tan x-1)^2}\\&
=\frac{\sec^2 x(\tan x-1)-(\tan x+1)\sec^2 x}{(\tan x-1)^2}\\&
=\frac{\sec^2x\tan x-\sec^2 x-\sec^2 x\tan x-\sec^2 x}{(\tan x-1)^2}\\&
=\frac{-2\sec^2 x}{(\tan x-1)^2}\\&
=-2\sec^2 x\frac{1}{(\tan x-1)^2}\\&
=-2\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-1\right)^2}\\&
=-2\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\frac{1}{\frac{(\sin x-\cos x)^2}{\cos^2 x}}\\&
=-2\frac{1}{\cos^2 x}\frac{\cos^2 x}{(\sin x-\cos x)^2}\\&
=-2\frac{1}{(\sin x-\cos x)^2}\\&
=-2\frac{1}{\sin^2x-2\sin x\cos x+\cos^2x}\\&
=-2\frac{1}{\color{red}{\sin^2x+\cos^2x}-\color{blue}{2\sin x\cos x}}\\&
=\frac{-2}{\color{red}{1}-\color{blue}{\sin2x}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: thank you very mush , i only have one question if u dont mind. on the fourth step how did =−2sec2x(tanx−1)2 became =−21cos2x1(sinxcosx−1)2

Comment: @Ahmdinho Musafa you mean the step $-2\frac{\sec^2x}{(\tan x-1)^2}=-2\frac{1}{\cos^2x}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}-1\right)^2}$?

Comment: yes i mean this one

Comment: @Ahmdinho Musafa i used the definition that say $\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$ and $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$

Comment: i got it now. thank you very mush :)